# Exception in System.Data.Entity.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, c#-4.0

I need to count the number of the rows in my database with the entity framework. I am using the LINQ method "Count".

Here is the code:

```
QvDb dba = new QvDb();
if (dba.KUser.Count(us => us.FacebookId == values["FacebookId"]) == 0)
```

As you can see the `values["FacebookId"]` it's a post array variable, and the `dba` object variable it's the database model builder.

When I am trying to access to the page i got this exception:

> An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in
> System.Data.Entity.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
> 'System.String get_Item(System.String)' method, and this method cannot
> be translated into a store expression.

For the record, the array is not null. It is a string that posted from the form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using LINQ to entities, all parts of your LINQ statement must be supported by the database.

`values["FacebookId"]` is a local dictionary.  So it cannot be executed on the remote SQL database.

Pull the value from the dictionary first into a local variable, then execute your LINQ statement.

```
QvDb dba = new QvDb();
var id = values["FacebookId"];
if (dba.KUser.Count(us => us.FacebookId == id) == 0)
```

Comment: Also, consider replacing `if (dba.KUser.Count(us => us.FacebookId == id) == 0)` by `if (!dba.KUser.Any(us => us.FacebookId == id))`.

Comment: @SimonBelanger can you explain why is it better than the == 0 ?

Comment: Performance wise, its the same. But semanticaly, you want to check if there 'isnt any' element and its more clear to do `!Any` than `Count() == 0`. It is not 'better'.